# Time of day as conditional in Vim

Tags: vim, vimrc

I'm working on improving my `.vimrc`, and I want to have command inside of it that depends upon whether it is night or day. I'd like to have something like the following in the end:

```
if isNightTime
  " do something
else
  " some other thing
endif
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Have you seen `:help time-functions` ?

Comment: Guess I hadn't seen that. I'm sorry for bothering folks before I'd sufficiently studied the documentation!

Comment: I didn't mean it that way, Vim's help can be a bit difficult to work with at first, that's why I pointed that page to you ;)

Comment: Didn't take any offense! :) Thanks, everyone, for being so helpful.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you doing that requires this type of switch? Is it related to a colorscheme?

Comment: @mattalexx Yeah, I'm using the [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) colorscheme, which has dark and light variants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the strftime() funtion is probably the best approach.  If you are satsified with one-hour resolution, you could do something like this:

```
let hour = strftime("%H")
if 6 <= hour && hour < 18
    " do daytime stuff
else
    " do nighttime stuff
endif
```

See

```
:help strftime()
```

and the strftime man page.